# How can I save a list in a while loop?

Tags: python

I want to make my while loop accumulate items in a list and I can't figure out how to do it.

this is what I have:

```
counter = 0
while counter != -1:
    animal = input("Please enter an animal name (or -1 to quit): ")
    if animal == "-1":
        break

sound = input("Please enter an animal sound: ")
if sound == "-1":
    break
    
grouped = []
animal = [animal]
sound = [sound]
grouped.append(animal, sound)
```

in the end it should look like this:

```
[[‘cow’,’moo’],[‘dog’,’woof’],[‘droid’,’beep’]]
```

Comment: follow ur logic, u want to acumulate animal names in the list animal .. after each time you provide a name u should add it to the list

Comment: Use the list [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method to add items to the list in the loop.

Comment: your like `while counter != -1:` looks confusing, as if it is a bug, but you probably intended the loop to only be terminated if  it reaches the `break` statement. In case that was your intention, you should explicitely write `while True:` because then it is obvious, what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = []
while True:
    animal = input("Please enter an animal name (or -1 to quit): ")
    if animal == "-1":
        break
    sound = input("Please enter an animal sound: ")
    result.append([animal, sound])
    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by reading them into two variables `animal`, `sound`, and checking them for `-1`. If they are not `-1` then append it in `animals`.

```
counter = 0
animals = []
while counter != -1:
    animal = input("Please enter an animal name (or -1 to quit): ")
    sound = input("Please enter an animal sound (or -1 to quit): ")
    if animal == "-1" or sound == "-1":
        break
    else:
      animals.append([animal,sound])

print(animals)
```

Input

```
cow
moo
dog
woof
droid
beep
-1
-1
```

Output

```
[[‘cow’,’moo’],[‘dog’,’woof’],[‘droid’,’beep’]]
```